# Java Regex not Matching

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("v(\\d\\.\\d)");
String s = "<a href>asldkjaskldj<>kljlaksjd v1.3<asdas>";
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(s).group());
```

How come this pattern isn't matching the 1.3?

Comment: Matches for me in `www.regexpal.com` (after appropriately unescaping backslashes).

Comment: yes I tested there and it works. It does not, however, work in my program.

Comment: Then show us your code demonstrating it does not work.

Comment: Well, show your program.

Comment: whoops, I miss: System.out.println(pattern.matcher(s).group());

Comment: nono, that's not what I meant - I mean with that last line, it still isn't finding 1.3

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("v(\\d\\.\\d)");
    String s = "<a href>asldkjaskldj<>kljlaksjd v1.3<asdas>";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Its matching v1.3.

Until you try to `find`,  the `group` will not give you the result

Comment: for some reason it's just not working for me. [example](http://i.imgur.com/LfXLgFN.png) true is `System.out.println(matcher.find());` and the target number I'm trying to pull is the 1.3 at the far right, top line

Comment: ok for some reason it's skipping over the first instance of a match and hitting the second... it's getting the v1.2 in the third line, now.

Answer (score 1):

i have tried this and it is working for me.

```
        String s = "<a href>asldkjaskldj<>kljlaksjd v1.3<asdas>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("v(\\d\\.\\d)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println("matches");
    }else{
        System.out.println("no match");
    }
```